# How prefix and suffix GCD works to solve the chosen one question

Tags: math, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to solve this question
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-chosen-one/problem where we have to find any integer  such that x is divisor of every array of int except for exactly one element.

After going through discussion and other reading material, I get that it is solved by using prefix and suffix GCD. I want to know how mathematically it got applied and reasoning behind such approach. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: GCD prefix is used to obtain greatest common divisor for strings. Not sure how to apply it to numbers? And why do you use `#grand-central-dispatch` tag?

Comment: I put gcd as tags and unfortunately, it got changed to grand-central-dispatch. Thanks for pointing that out